# Flip animation not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I followed [this tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)  to incorporate a card flip on my website.  I learned the important lesson of not letting [your website](http://www.wienerwedding.com/wedding_party) go live without testing on all major browsers, because the animation doesn't work correctly on Firefox--it just flips back and forth.  I know I'm supposed to add vendor prefixes, and I think I got them all but possibly not.

**note**:  Some general advice as to how to go about debugging this in Firefox would also be greatly appreciated.  I usually use Chrome, and I'm not great with that.

css

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;

}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
    0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    0px 0px 0px 14px #fff,
    0px 0px 0px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    6px 6px 8px 17px #555;

    -moz-box-shadow:
    0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    0px 0px 0px 14px #fff,
    0px 0px 0px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    6px 6px 8px 17px #555;

    box-shadow:
    0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    0px 0px 0px 14px #fff,
    0px 0px 0px 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    6px 6px 8px 17px #555;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #99CCFF;
}

.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    margin: 20px 26px 32px 26px;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}

.flipper {
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;


    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .back, .flip-container.hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front, .flip-container.hover .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

html

```
    <div class='wedding_party_row'>
        <div class='wedding_party_row_contents'>
            <div class = 'wedding_party_header'>
                The Officiant
            </div>
            <div class='wedding_party_member'>
               <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('onmouseover');">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <div class="party_image"><img /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="party_text_container">

                            <div class="party_text">Blah blah</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to make *just* a flip:
You tried to accomplish too many rotations at once compared to David Walsh's example.
I've commented out the latter `transform: rotate` rules and therefore it works in Firefox.

**Edit Updated jsfiddle with cleanup**
See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/n27qM/4/ 
I've also added some comments for better code in my jsfiddle, like *getting rid of -moz-box-shadow* (just for Fx < 4.0) or *don't include value units on values that are '0'* and so on.

Regarding your question on general advice: Firefox' own developer tools are a good start, but the best tool in my opinion is Firebug. For a comparison of the two see [What unique features does Firebug have that are not built-in to Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180494/firefox-which-advantages-does-firebug-still-have-over-the-integrated-developer)

Or put your code not only into your question, but also on jsfiddle, so others can start fiddling around immediately! ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, it looked like there were some redundancies there.  I'll check it out in a bit.